# Change text of TextView in PopupWindow not working

Tags: java, android, textview, popupwindow, viewgroup

I'm having problems dynamically changing the text in a `TextView` in a `PopupWindow` in Android. I've referenced the `TextView` element inside the `PopupWindow` by using a `LayoutInflater` and `ViewGroup` but the text is not updating. Any help would be very much appreciated! :)

My code is as follows:

```
private void popupWindow() {
        try {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) SwingSpeed.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_recording,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
            pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_recording,
                    null, false), 480, 800, true);
            pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.swingspeed), Gravity.CENTER, 0,
                    0);
            recording_text = (TextView) layout
                    .findViewById(R.id.recording_text);
            recording_text.setText("Recording"); //Update the TextView  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is: you are inflating the layout two times,
instead of:

```
recording_text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.recording_text);
```

do this:

```
recording_text = (TextView) pw.getContentView().
                 findViewById(R.id.recording_text);
```

and also, you don't need this line at all:

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_recording,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
```